# From where takes swagger codegen maven plugin the naming for the ApiController etc?

Tags: java, spring, maven, swagger, codegen

I cant figure out from where the swagger codegen takes the naming for the RestApiController, RestApi Interface and RestApiDelegate. Rest is the generated Name, so it also could be something like StackoverFlowApiController.

With the flag modelNamePrefix it just prefixes the model classes.

Answer (score 0):

Already found it, so I will answer it for google users etc:

it's defined over the path in your swagger specification (for example your swagger.yml).